# What is the name of a theorem which says that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals, then $\alpha\in\beta$, or $\beta\in\alpha$, or $\alpha=\beta$?

Tags: reference-request, ordinals

[This Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402249/how-to-compare-ordinal-numbers) contains the following information:

> There is a theorem which says given any two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, exactly one of the following holds: $\alpha\in\beta$, or $\beta\in\alpha$, or $\alpha=\beta$.

What is the name of this theorem and where can I find it?

Comment: Ordinal Membership is Trichotomy - https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordinal_Membership_is_Trichotomy

Comment: First let me clarify a bit here regarding the question/answers in the linked thread. For ordinals less than $\epsilon_0$ we often write a single ordinals in multiple ways. For example, we could write either $\omega^\omega$ or $\omega^2+\omega^\omega$ etc. This is perhaps somewhat analogous to how we can write $7$, $(5+(2 \cdot 1))$, $(2+(5 \cdot 1))$ and so on. The point in the linked question was that if we are given a "finite string" which uses the alphabet $\{+,\cdot,e,(,),\omega,0,s \}$ ($e$ is for exponent, $s$ for successor), then there are two further questions.

Comment: $(1)$ Is it decidable in a (strict) algorithmic sense whether a given string from these alphabet forms a "valid" expression? $(2)$ Is it decidable whether the ordinals that two different strings represent are same or not? And if not, which one is greater? The answer to both of these questions is positive (that's all that I was trying to say in the answer to linked question).

Comment: Given your comment in the other question, I think what you might be meaning to ask is that: "Suppose we are given two well-orders (of $\mathbb{N}$) say $W_1,W_2$ with order-types $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ respectively. Then is there a "reasonable sense" in which we can compare $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ and determine which one is greater? And if one of them is greater, then can we find the "address" (very informally speaking ... this needs to be made precise) of the smaller ordinal?" I think the answer to that would depend on what do we mean by a "reasonable sense".

Comment: @SSequence: but is it always possible to provide a precise description for an arbitrary ordinal using a finite string? For example, what language (and alphabet) would we use to describe [this ordinal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911530/is-it-possible-to-base-the-slow-growing-hierarchy-on-the-ordinal-defined-as-the)?

Comment: The answer in the linked question was specifically for ordinals less than $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: But is this theorem valid for any pair of arbitrarily chosen ordinals?

Comment: For example, in infinite models (such as ORM) given the relations $lessthan_1: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and $lessthan_2: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ one can determine (giving the ORM "oracle access" to  $lessthan_1$ and $lessthan_2$) : $(a)$ whether they can ever represent a well-order relations on $\mathbb{N}$ (with any order-type) $(b)$ Suppose $lessthan_1,lessthan_2$ can both serve as well-order relations. So if we consider these functions as well-order relations (for well-orders $W_1,W_2$ on $\mathbb{N}$) then can we decide which of $W_1,W_2$ one has greater order-type? Yes.

Comment: What does ORM abbreviation stand for?

Comment: @lyricallywicked "Ordinal Register Machine"

Comment: Also, to be formally correct, I think I should have written $lessequals: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ (with obvious meaning) instead of $lessthan: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ in the comment above. I was a bit careless about this in my answer to your previous question too.

Comment: "But is this theorem valid for any pair of arbitrarily chosen ordinals?" Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the **trichotomy principle** (or **law of trichotomy**, or etc.) for ordinals. It can also be phrased for arbitrary well-orderings, as follows:

> For any two well-orderings $A,B$, exactly one of the following situations occurs: $(i)$ there is a non-surjective order-preserving embedding of $A$ into $B$; $(ii)$ there is a non-surjective order-preserving embedding of $B$ into $A$; $(iii)$ there is an order-preserving bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Intuitively, $(i)$ means $A<B$, $(ii)$ means $B<A$, and $(iii)$ means $A=B$. *(Exercise: the principle above does in fact imply trichotomy for ordinals as you've phrased it.)* Note also that we can replace "embedding" with "*initial segment* embedding" (= embedding whose image is an initial segment).

You can find proofs of the trichotomy in any decent introductory set theory textbook - for example, it's Theorem $6.3$ in [Kunen's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444868399) (phrased there in terms of arbitrary well-orderings).

Note that nowhere do we need to assume that the ordinals (or well-orderings) involved are countable; this is a generally, always-applying principle. Also, to forestall a frequent (in my experience) confusion, note that it does *not* need the axiom of choice (rather, *replacement* is the key principle).